# Safely Sending Email from PHP

Tags: php, email

I've got a page on my website where users can send me a message by giving their email, name, and a message. On the front end (JS) I do some basic verification, make sure the email is formatted like an email, make sure the other boxes aren't blank, and then I send it to PHP by GET.

Now I'm aware people can do some pretty sneaky stuff by injecting malicious code into PHP. What precautions should I be taking? When I was working with MySQL, I would escape it using the mysqli escape function. What should I be doing here?

Here's my script right now:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET["message"]) || !isset($_GET["name"]) || !isset($_GET["email"])){
        echo "Check all the fields are correctly filled in and try again!";
        die();
    }
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    if($email == ""|| $message == "" || $name == ""){
        echo "Check all the fields are correctly filled in and try again!";
        die();
    }

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    mail("email@email.com","A Message From " . $name,$message,"From: $email\n");
    echo "success";
?>
```

Comment: Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), it handles that for you. As a bonus PHPMailer actually gives you errors if something fails, 'mail()' just return true/false and you're left clueless. And for MySQL you should use PDO or Mysqli and bind the parameters using prepared/parameterized queries, not the "real escape function"

Comment: First, use POST if you don't "have" to use GET because GETs can be altered in the URL. Then, look up XSS form injection.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way is that you can declare a variable (for example `$pattern`)and store regular expressions (like patterns used commonly in attacks) in it, then  use `preg_match($pattern, $valueFromYourForm)` method to see if any of the passed values matches any of those expressions and then you can stop the execution.

Comment: Some times this is the best you can do, I guess. But be aware relying on black lists are considered bad practice security wise. When you can you should always compare to a white list - as it's much easier to exploit/circumvent a black list.